# Run command `at ` 5 seconds from now

Tags: linux, bash, scheduled-tasks

As part of a slightly complex script, I need to tell a server to run a simulation. Normally, I would achieve this by doing `ssh user@server 'simulation/script'`. However, doing so would keep the ssh session alive until `'simulation/script'` is done, which is undesirable to me.

I recently learned about the `at` command, and it seems to fit into my problem well.
What I want to do now is to ssh into my server, and `at` my simulation script to run in 5 seconds (more than enough time for the ssh connection to be closed). Thus, once the ssh connection is closed within 5 seconds, the server will start the simulation without needing the ssh connection to stay alive.

What I'm having trouble with is the time expression that `at` needs in order to schedule a job "5 seconds from now"

I have tried the following time expressions, all of which give me errors:

```
now + 5 seconds
now + 5 sec
now + 5 s
now + 5seconds
now + 5sec
now + 5 s
now+5sec
now+5seconds
now+5s
```

How can I get my `at` to run my command "5 seconds from now"?

Comment: Rather than messing around with `at`, perhaps you just want `ssh user@server bash -c '"simulation/script &"'`...

Comment: I'm using it inside of a `package.json` script so I had to do this to prevent the process from being blocked: `( sleep 5 && delayed_command ) & immediate_command`. I also added `> /dev/null 2>&1` after the `delayed_command` if you don't want the output to show up in `STDOUT`.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter this is the only answer that worked.   I wanted to display an image using qlmanage for a a few seconds while continuing have a terminal session active, not asleep.  Using background & worked fine,   tho i did need to wrap in an additional set of prens.   using bash 3.2 on macos.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no *seconds* in at :

`man at` said :

> - specification of a date must follow the specification of the time of day.  You can also give times like now + count time-units,
>     where the time-units can be minutes, hours, days, or weeks and
>         you can tell at to run the job today by suffixing the time with today and to run the job tomorrow by suffixing the time with
>     tomorrow.

So instead of `at`, you could use a `sleep` I think.

See `man 1 sleep`

---

If you'd like to run `ssh user@server 'simulation/script'` without waiting, simply do :

```
ssh user@server 'simulation/script' &
```

the command will run in the background.

Moreover, as Rawkode said, `nohup` will help there.

So finally :

```
nohup ssh user@server 'simulation/script' &
```

with nohup, you can quit your terminal and have the `ssh` process alive.

---

`EDIT`: if you want to run the `ssh` command and close the connection :

```
ssh user@server 'simulation/script &'
```

Comment: but if I `&` the `ssh`, won't the socket still stay open?

Comment: The socket will close after the script is finish

Comment: That's a problem for me. I need the socket to close before the script starts

Comment: using `&` won't work because I have to manually kill the ssh connection with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>. This is not automatable. I need to automate, kill the ssh connection and run the script. This is why I thought of `now`. I think I should just bite the bullet and do `now + 1 minute`

Comment: By default, ssh will close after running the command in remote background. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: The problem is much more complex than described in my OP (I was trying to reduce the noise). Essentially, the remote script takes a long time (2-4 hours) to run. So I don't want the ssh connection to stay alive for that long. So I might as well use `now + 1 minute`

Comment: @sputnick but 'sleep' will not act asynchronously. Say I want to do one thing 5 seconds from now, and a different thing 6 seconds from now. How would I do that with sleep? (without specifying that the second thing should be started 1 second after the end of the first sleep)?

Answer (score 37):

"at" doesn't have sub-minute resolution but you can fake it:

```
echo "sleep 5 ; COMMAND" | at now
```

Comment: This is what I came up with as well, and it tested to work ala `echo "sleep 23; date > /tmp/date.txt" | at 13:30` and just after 13:30:23 the contents of /tmp/date.txt were indeed "... 13:30:23..."

Comment: I reduced this to `sleep 5 ; COMMAND` and it worked. It has the upshot of running the command in the current environment (including the X server) which is useful when you want to create a screenshot after some seconds: `sleep 5 ; import -window root ~/screen_$(date "+%F_%H-%M-%S").png`

Comment: Maybe then it is better to not use `at` and switch to something like `nohup bash -c "sleep 5 ; COMMAND" & disown` ? Because `at` is not always present and requires a service to run (need to enable it).

Answer (score 12):

`at` doesn't use seconds, only minutes/hours/days

What you can do is precede your script with `nohup`, which will ensure the script isn't killed when you disconnect your SSH session.

`ssh server 'nohup yourscript.sh &'`

**NOTE:** Having just played with the above, the SSH connection has to be killed manually.

Another alternative would be `screen`

`screen -d -m yourscript.sh`

This will launch a detached `screen` process that you can reattach to at any time later.

**NOTE:** I've tested this with the following script and command and it worked perfectly.

**SSH command**

`ssh server.com 'screen -d -m ~/myscript.sh'`

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10
echo "hello world" > /tmp/hello
exit;
```

Comment: How does the `nohup` help? I've never used it before…

Comment: `nohup` won't kill the command on your disconnection. I know you've already gone with `at 1 minute`, but i'll update my answer for future reference for others.

Comment: I'm still interested in the `nohup` implementation (possibly for future projects), so thank you for making the effort. Would I have to manually kill the ssh connection, or could that be automated with `nohup`

Comment: If you put the command in your `ssh` line, `ssh` will exit after the command has executed. `ssh server 'command'`

Comment: Is there a way to make `ssh` kill the connection before the end of execution of the remote command, while keeping the remote command alive in the remote host (this is why I went with scheduling the job as opposed to `ssh` with `nohup`)?

Comment: I've updated again. `screen` is going to be your best bet I believe. I was so sure that `nohup` could automatically be sent to background, but I can't replicate on my CentOS box. I'll continue to play with it and report my findings, but let me know if `screen` is a viable alternative for you.

Comment: `screen` /is/ viable. Really, my biggest concern is that I can close the ssh connection without having to wait for the remote script to finish running (as it takes a really long time - 2-4 hours)

Comment: Then the script/screen/ssh command I posted above, does just that.

Comment: You might also want to use `ssh -n` (or `ssh -f`) to immediately detach the process from SSH (that will address your first note).

Answer (score 8):

Just to note: in `man at`, I saw there is a `-t` switch, which will accept date times with seconds - but unfortunately the seconds will be truncated:

```
$ date; date --date="now +10 seconds" +"%m%d%H%M.%S"; echo "logger AAAA" | at -t $(date --date="now +5 seconds" +"%Y%m%d%H%M.%S")
Thu Feb  5 14:45:57 CET 2015
02051446.07
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 8 at Thu Feb  5 14:46:00 2015
```

... and so the job may actually be scheduled in the past (also, used `logger` to syslog, because it doesn't look like echoing to terminals' stdout can work from here)

Comment: Seconds are actually considered under MacOS

Answer (score 3):

I think it is much easier doing:

```
sleep n && command
```

where `n` is number of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting stdin/stdout/stderr in addition to backgrounding the script will allow the SSH session to close immediately after executing the backgrounded command:

```
ssh hostname "/path/to/script </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &"
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/36436/138334.

Comment: Don't you also need `nohup` to avoid the process being killed when the SSH session is closed?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using  sleep command like that:

```
bash -c 'sleep 5 ; echo "test"' &
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today, but I was able to resolve it using `nohup`

`nohup bash -c 'sleep 5 && at now -f script-name.sh'`