# Application calling rpm to update itself problems

Tags: linux, unix, rpm, yum, dnf

I am trying to allow a application to update itself by calling an RPM packet manager (right now DNF) to install an RPM containing an update. The problem is that when the packet manager uninstalls the application, the service is stopped and the packet manager is killed before it can install the new RPM.

Is there any way to detach the packet manager process so it can finish the update?

Comment: Application should not call `rpm` command to update `self`. It should be done through the spec file. Share your RPM spec `application.spec` file. It sounds like the packaging is done wrong.

Comment: I am a little confused be the later part. The `spec` file is used to create the RPM and program behaviors for commands given by the packet manager (remove, install, update,). If the application cannot call `rpm` then how can it use the `spec` file to trigger an update.

Comment: That's where it's wrong, it shouldn't call `rpm` from spec file. Your question that when "`dnf` installs it, service restarts, process killed and install fails", this part sounds like problem with spec file.

Comment: Gotcha, unfortunately the spec file is generated by Yocto, so it would be hard to change. But i might be doing a remove then install that would cause this behavior. I might avoid it with just an update

Comment: I would still prefer to just orphan a child proc to do whatever i need it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how much control you have over how the update is run.

One possible option is to put a check for updates, and the update itself, in a program that is run by a cron job.  It's common for RPMs to install cron jobs, and  the cron job won't be stopped if the service associated with the application is stopped.

If the update must be started directly by the service, and you can control how the update is invoked, then you could use the [at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) command to run it.  See [Run command 'at' 5 seconds from now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13905886/4154375) for examples of using `at`.  The update would be run by a separate service, so it wouldn't be stopped when your service is stopped.  However, this requires `at` to be  installed and the [atd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/atd) daemon to be running.

Comment: You could also use `systemd-run` (or directly connect to the associated DBus interface from the application) to start a detached process.  But I'd agree with all the other posters that an application running RPM or Yum to force an update is a horrible idea in the first place - that's just not how the packaging system is designed to operate.